# Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll when reference to Microsoft.Phone in Windows Phone 8.1 app template

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Microsoft just released Windows App 8.1 with combination of Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, so you can create a universal app. However, it gives me a trouble to add Microsoft.Phone 8.1 assembly to project reference.

Here is what I did (in Visual Studio 2013, with Rc2 installed)
1> Create New project from Visual C#->Store Apps -> Windows Phone Apps. 
2> Added Microsoft.Phone from this location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1

3> Now, do a build, I see the following Error: "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorilib.dll"

Anyone has the similar experience? any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: When creating an universal app, you're using the WinRT API. I don't think you're supposed to reference a Silverlight assembly.

Comment: that is how I thought in the first place. In the default project, it added the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK as a reference, however when I tried to using Microsoft.Phone.Notification, it is not available for me to use... So that is why I added reference. So I may have missed something really simple...

Comment: The notification system is different on WinRT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications

Comment: Hmmm, that could be the case, although I have not see any document about it. I will certain give it a try once I get around and report back what I found.

Comment: KooKiz is correct. Windows Phone 8.1 has been changed completely, well, sort of. So for push message, you can treat it as Windows Store App... Which makes sense... So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a few API changes as part of programming model in windows phone 8.1 apps.
have a look at this link.
It will solve your problem.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraswadehra/archive/2014/08/21/how-to-send-email-from-your-windows-phone-8-1-app.aspx